# How to get the dialed number in Stasis app

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

I am trying to wrap my head around ARI and Asterisk, my goal is to dial from an extension to another. I dialed 5001 from extension 5002. Now in the stasisStart function, I want to create a new channel, and used the dialed number (5001) and pass 'PJSIP/5001' to the endpoint. How do I get the dialed number?

Dialplan:

```
exten  => _500Z, 1, Stasis(test-app)
```

test-app.js

```
    function stasisStart(event, channel) {

    // I want to dial 'PJSIP/5001' (the dialed number)
    client.channels.originate({ endpoint: 'PJSIP/5001', app: 'test-app' },)
    .then(function (originatedChannel) {
        console.log(' originated ');
        console.log(util.format('originated channel id %s  - name: %s', originatedChannel.id, originatedChannel.name));
    })
    .catch(function (err) { console.log('error happened'); });

}


Channel  
id: "1603812843.140"
name: "PJSIP/5002-0000004e"
state: "Ring"
caller: {"name":"","number":"5002"}
connected: {"name":"","number":""}
accountcode: ""
dialplan: {"context":"internal","exten":"5001","priority":1,"app_name":"Stasis","app_data":"test-app"}
creationtime: "2020-10-27T11:34:03.251-0400"
language: "en"
```

Comment: Not this ?  "exten":"5001"

Comment: yes, i want to get the 5001 in the code

Comment: my goal is to add the channel to a bridge and start a call

Comment: But you HAVE that in a code! It is in your dump!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this example that works. I guess I was confused about the endpoint, I thought I had to specify it in the dialplan, but not.

```
/**
 *  This example shows how a call can be originated from a channel entering a
 *  Stasis application to an endpoint. The endpoint channel will then enter the
 *  Stasis application and the 2 channels will be placed into a mixing bridge.
 *      exten => _500Z,1,NoOp()
 *      same => n,Stasis(originate-example)
 *      same => n,Hangup()
 */

'use strict';

var client = require('ari-client');

var ENDPOINT = 'PJSIP/5001'; // TODO: enter your endpoint here


// TODO: replace with your Asterisk instance: host, user and secret
client.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk', 
    /**
     *  Setup event listeners and start application.
     *
     *  @callback connectCallback
     *  @memberof originate-example
     *  @param {Error} err - error object if any, null otherwise
     *  @param {module:ari-client~Client} ari - ARI client
     */
    function (err, ari) {

  // Use once to start the application to ensure this listener will only run
  // for the incoming channel
  ari.once('StasisStart',
      /**
       *  Once the incoming channel has entered Stasis, answer it and originate
       *  call to the endpoint (outgoing channel).
       *
       *  @callback incomingStasisStartCallback
       *  @memberof originate-example
       *  @param {Object} event - the full event object
       *  @param {module:resources~Channel} incoming -
       *    the incoming channel entering Stasis
       */
      function (event, incoming) {

    incoming.answer(function (err) {
      originate(incoming);
    });
  });

  /**
   *  Originate the outgoing channel
   *
   *  @function originate
   *  @memberof originate-example
   *  @param {module:resources~Channel} incoming - the incoming channel that
   *    will originate the call to the endpoint
   */
  function originate (incoming) {
    incoming.once('StasisEnd',
        /**
         *  If the incoming channel ends, hangup the outgoing channel.
         *
         *  @callback incomingStasisEndCallback
         *  @memberof originate-example
         *  @param {Object} event - the full event object
         *  @param {module:resources~Channel} channel -
         *    the incoming channel leaving Stasis
         */
        function (event, channel) {

      outgoing.hangup(function (err) {});
    });

    var outgoing = ari.Channel();

    outgoing.once('ChannelDestroyed',
        /**
         *  If the endpoint rejects the call, hangup the incoming channel.
         *
         *  @callback outgoingChannelDestroyedCallback
         *  @memberof originate-example
         *  @param {Object} event - the full event object
         *  @param {module:resources~Channel} channel -
         *    the channel that was destroyed
         */
        function (event, channel) {

      incoming.hangup(function (err) {});
    });

    outgoing.once('StasisStart',
        /**
         *  When the outgoing channel enters Stasis, create a mixing bridge
         *  and join the channels together.
         *
         *  @callback outgoingStasisStartCallback
         *  @memberof originate-example
         *  @param {Object} event - the full event object
         *  @param {module:resources~Channel} outgoing -
         *    the outgoing channel entering Stasis
         */
        function (event, outgoing) {

      var bridge = ari.Bridge();

      outgoing.once('StasisEnd',
          /**
           *  If the outgoing channel ends, clean up the bridge.
           *
           *  @callback outgoingStasisEndCallback
           *  @memberof originate-example
           *  @param {Object} event - the full event object
           *  @param {module:resources~Channel} channel -
           *    the outgoing channel leaving Stasis
           */
          function (event, channel) {

        bridge.destroy(function (err) {});
      });

      outgoing.answer(
          /**
           *  Once the outgoing channel has been answered, create a mixing
           *  bridge and add the incoming and outgoing channels to it.
           *
           *  @callback outgoingAnswerCallback
           *  @memberof originate-example
           *  @param {Error} err - error object if any, null otherwise
           */
          function (err) {

        bridge.create({type: 'mixing'},
            /**
             *  Once the mixing bridge has been created, join the incoming and
             *  outgoing channels to it.
             *
             *  @callback bridgeCreateCallback
             *  @memberof originate-example
             *  @param {Error} err - error object if any, null otherwise
             *  @param {module:resources~Bridge} bridge - the newly created
             *    mixing bridge
             */
            function (err, bridge) {

          bridge.addChannel(
            {channel: [incoming.id, outgoing.id]},
            function (err) {}
          );
        });
      });
    });

    var playback = ari.Playback();
    incoming.play({media: 'sound:vm-dialout'}, playback, function (err) {});

    // Originate call from incoming channel to endpoint
    outgoing.originate(
      {endpoint: ENDPOINT, app: 'originate-example', appArgs: 'dialed'},
      function (err, channel) {}
    );
  }

  // can also use ari.start(['app-name'...]) to start multiple applications
  ari.start('originate-example');
});
```

Comment: This code DOES NOT answer your question :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in the dialplan as argument, like:

`exten  => _500Z, 1, Stasis(test-app, ${EXTEN})`

Then you can get it (and any other args you want to pass) at `event.args[0]`

Or you could get it from `channel.dialplan.exten`